# How can I stop my lava moat from burning down my house?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a house in Minecraft and since wood planks was the most abundant resource in my inventory, that is what I made it out of.  I put a lava moat around my house for defensive purposes.  My house keep catching on fire, how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118468/minimum-safe-spacing-between-lava-and-flamable-materials

Comment: I would recommend against building the moat bridge out of wood, for starters.  And I would probably line it with cobblestone as a precaution, and build your house at least 5 tiles away, as seen in the answers given so far.

Comment: Also be careful, sometimes fire can travel through solid blocks.  I found this out the hard way when Coal Blocks first showed up (in a weekly snapshot) I nearly burned down my whole house seeing how long the Coal Block took to burn out

Comment: I'm looking for an answer that  1. will not cover my house with water, 2. not make my moat incredibally far from my house, and 3. not be made with blocks that aren't very abundant. im on a beach, in a large biome world, with mining being tedios b/c of sand and gravel.

Comment: I just want to point out that answers that say 5x5x2 or something like this are a little misleading. 5x5 is centered on the block in question with it being 2 blocks high, so as long as it is at least 3 blocks away from the center(lava block) nothing should catch on fire. So it should be something like this - [E] [B] [B] [L] [B] [B] [E] the [E] blocks should be unaffected

Comment: You could just set the gamerule `doFireTick` to `false` using `gamerule doFireTick false`. This will disable fire spread globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply move your lava moat further away. [This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/118525/63072) answer says:

> Fire can also be born from lava. Fire is always created above the lava position. Fire can be created in a 5x5x2 shape above it

So you just need to move it about 5 blocks away from any flammable material.

Additional, you can build a wall of cobblestone or glass (any non-flammable material) around your house to protect it from the fire.

Comment: Fiery flames. Redundant much? :)

Comment: [Department of Redundancy Department](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DepartmentOfRedundancyDepartment)

Answer (score 3):

A resource cheap way, if you don't care about looks, is using water as a "shield" around your house. Pour it so it covers most of your house, except the door, and have it run down into a second moat. Have a border of dirt between your lava and water moat so the water doesn't put the lava out. This will not look top of the line, but will help out if your resources are limited. Iron is easy to come by, and water is too. This will also shield against creepers blowing your house up, if they ever manage to get close enough. And if you happen to fall into the lava moat by accident, you have water right there to put you out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a wall of non-flammible blocks above the inside of your moat.  Glass would work.  Make sure no trees or other flammible blocks are hanging over or through the wall, though.