# Can wood catch fire if it's surrounded by water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Are there any arrangements of water around wood that can prevent it from catching fire? I'm mostly interested in structures with these three cross-sections:

```
~██~   ▒██▒   ▒██▒   █ Wood
~~~~   ~~~~   ▒~~▒   ~ Water
                     ▒ Air
```

These arrangements will be in a [waterslide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEbRoofYMEw&t=1m01s) that may or may not catch fire at some point.

Comment: There is a [related question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9344/properties-of-fire) about properties of fire but it doesn't address the effects of fire around water.

Comment: I don't think water changes anything, but sadly it'll take some time for me to make sure

Comment: Bad jokes about my name will be the death of me

Comment: Sadly, you wont be able to restrain us from telling bad jokes. About your question, i think the first possibility will not witness fire spread. Can't tell for sure, though, so i'll make a few try this evening...

Comment: @Lysarion I need a definite answer or my poor waterslide might suffer :P also, if anyone submits an answer please discuss water above wood if it makes a difference.

Comment: I guess this is a top-down view? Or is it a cross-section diagram?

Comment: @Kevin Y Cross-sections. Updated my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears water doesn't stop logs from catching fire, as they caught fire in all of these configurations (I lit the Netherrack blocks on fire for all the tests).

---

Water underneath:

[image]

---

Water on the sides:

[image]

---

Mixture of configuration 1 and 2:

[image]

---

Water flowing right to the logs:

[image]

Comment: +1, water seems to function like a normal non-flammable block for the purposes of fires. I've been trying to to prove it, but I couldn't think of that second configuration that you have