# Is this Fireplace Safe?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a wood house that I'm rather proud of. I've built a fireplace that seem safe, but I don't want to risk burning my house down. I've seen plenty of tutorials online for making safe fireplaces, but most of them are more than 1 year old, and possibly obsolete. I tried reading the Minecraft Wiki article on fire, but it gets pretty wordy and difficult to understand. Is the fireplace pictured below safe?

View from inside. (The wood planks in the fireplace will be the fuel, and eventually replaced with netherrack):
[image: View from inside.]

Up close view. (Fuel has been removed):
[image: Up close view.]

Outside view. (4 dirt blocks have been removed to show base of chimney):
[image: Outside view]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To answer your question, I decided to experiment with your build. I tried to replicate your fireplace as accurately as I could, while limiting the size of the structure surrounding it:

[image]

I tried to keep the base structure of the fireplace as close to identical as I could.

[image]

I first attempted the fire with the wood planks shown in your pictures:

[image]

Unfortunately, the wood burned down to nothing, and the fire eventually died. I then tried it with Netherrack.

[image]

Everything seemed to be going well. I thought I'd successfully completed the experiment, when suddenly:

[image]

**EVERYTHING QUICKLY WENT HORRIBLY WRONG!!**

The end result to follow:

[image]

Alas, my structure (house) was destroyed. I feel I didn't even get to know my creation, for it died within minutes of me setting the fire.

Long story short, **NO**. The fire *will* spread to your house.

*five wooden blocks were harmed in the making of this answer*

**EDIT** It is worth noting, however, that out of the 4 times I've rebuilt/retested, every time the fire has *started* at the bushes along the outside of the fireplace.

[image]

Comment: I will say, though... I have no idea why only one side of the house was affected.

Comment: I also tried this in creative mode yesterday, and it successfully survived 2 days and 2 nights. Good thing I asked!

Comment: @Sonic42 Also, after ~2 in-game days, the entire structure (i.e. every piece of wood surrounding the brick) was gone.

Comment: Try doubled wooden slabs. I think the bug where they don't burn is still present.

Comment: @Broam If you mean as fuel for the fire, that's what I did. They did in fact burn.

Comment: Pity. Some buildings we've made are now flammable. :/

Answer (score 32):

I would say no
From the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fire)

> More precisely, a fire block can turn any air block into fire that is adjacent to a flammable block and up to one block downwards, one block sideways (including diagonals), and four blocks upwards.

Also, [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/9346/11582) answer would suggest not as well.

Comment: +1 as while the other one gives the answer 'No' this actually gives the rules of fire so a proper fireplace could be created.

Comment: I really like how the first answer is almost completely empirical with little mention of the minecraft rules for how fire works/spread and this answer is almost completely explaining the rules of minecraft (aka theoretical answer).

Comment: And it explains Fluttershy’s last picture: the fire lit the air block above the bush block which is one block above and one block diagonally to the side of the fire. As to why it always lit the same side, that’s probably either chance due to the build, or a function of the update algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version this was when it was first posted, however, following the wiki, we can identify exactly how fires are started.

> Fire will spread over flammable surfaces. [...] This can happen at a distance of up to one block downwards, one block sideways (including diagonals), and four blocks upwards of the original fire block (not the block the fire is on/next to). Therefore if the player is using fire to build a fireplace, caution is needed. Blocks in the way will not prevent fire from igniting blocks above it—so even if you protect your wooden roof with cobblestone between it and the fire, the fire will completely ignore that cobblestone.

To test this, I built a little experiment:

[image: Control]
[image: Test]

As you can see, both of these are set up within the parameters of the reach of the spread. Needless to say:

[image: Fire Control - Burning]
[image: Fire Test - Burning]

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fire#Spread)